# Codeigniter modular extensions HMVC won't load view

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I am using the modular extensions HMVC add on for codeigniter.

my structure looks as follows:

modules/
-manager/
--controllers/
---manager.php
--views/
---index.php

the manager.php controller:

```
class Manager extends MX_Controller {

  function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();

  }

  function index(){


   $data['newsletter'] = Newsletter::all();

   $this->load->view('index',$data);

  }

}
```

Routing and printing from inside the controller itself works fine, but I can't seem to load a view, get a codeigniter error saying the view file can't be found

/modules/manager/config/routes.php:

```
<?php

$route['module_name'] = 'manager';
```

It seems the views are still being called from CI's main view folder, not sure why they are not calling from the modules folder because the controller is extending the MX class

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->load->view('manager/index',$data);
```

Structure for folders:

```
apllication
    modules
       manager
           config
               routes.php
           controllers
               manager.php
           views
               index.php
```

Comment: Change it to ``$route['manager'] = 'Manager';`` and try my code.

Comment: Sorry, but I not understand you.

Comment: no dice is just an expression meaning it didnt work - So thanks, i tried that as well but it didn't work

Comment: what is the `Newsletter` it's controller or model?

Comment: Thats a Model in the php-activerecord style - that is not the source of the problem, i can print the data from that method from within the controller without issue

Comment: Very strangely. I tested your and my code in my localhost, and view is rendering fine. I use CI v.2.1.4 and latest version of HMVC. Also, I put empty array to view instead ``Newsletter::all()``.

Comment: Ok i gather the views are still for some reason being loaded from the main views folder, not the one within the module itself...

Comment: I'm not too familiar with that particular HMVC module but I think you have to specify the module's view directory if you want to load your views from the module's base directory.